# Is this map open?

Tags: functional-analysis

$T\in L(C[0,1]) $ defined by $T(f)= f-\int_{0}^{1}f$. Is this linear map surjective.
I am trying and I thought it's true but not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: What is $\int_0^1T(f)$? Remember that $\int_0^1f$ is a constant.

Alternatively, again remembering that $\int_0^1f$ is a constant function, what constant functions are in the image of $T$?

Comment: $\int_{0}^{1}T(f) =0$. Image of T contains all function such that integration zero.

Comment: @FirojSk Exactly. In fact, $T$ is a _projection_ onto that subspace.

Comment: Is Im(T)=${f:\int_{0}^{1}f=0}$?

Comment: @FirojSK As I said: Exactly. In fact, $T$ is a _projection_ onto that subspace. Also, since `{}` carry special meaning in math environments on this site, if you want $\{\}$, you have to use backslashes: `\{\}`.